# How to run Django on Unix server (MobaXterm)?

Tags: linux, python, django, mobaxterm

While server (127.0.0.1) works just fine on PC using Pycharm which uses the Django 'GUI' framework, I've tried to execute the command on unix server (MobaXterm) but it just says that 10.1...1..69 (my own PC IP address) refused to connect.

I've changed the ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']. But still, it doesn't work.

By running [file leading to python directory]/python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080, there is a starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8080/.

However, when I tried to open this in Chrome (http://10.1...1..69:8080/), it just says it refused to connect.

Can I check if I did everything correctly? Are there any additional steps that I need to make amendments to in order to run Django on Unix server (MobaXterm)?

Comment: Hi all. I was actually thinking if the whole Pycharm Project folder (which mainly contains GUI) can actually be stored as an application which in turn can be opened from MobaXterm (Unix server)? Will it open for anyone who is on the server? If so, how do I do that? Any comments and solutions will be a great help, thank you.